# How to find out from a Java class method whether there is an object of another, given, Java class?

Tags: java, object, netbeans-platform, discovery

Good day!
I have an Apache Netbeans module with several Java classes in it. I'd like to find out when executing a method belonging to an object of, say, class A if another class (class B) had already been instantiated and in this case discover what is this object so that I can call one of its methods from the class A object method. So I am not trying to find out the class of a given object, I am trying to find if there is an object of a given class.
Any ideas?
Thanks! Erminio.

I didn't try any code because I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: You can put a public static field on A of type B and set it from B's constructor. This sounds like a bad design however. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Yeah, setting static fields/publishing the object inside the constructor is typically a bad idea - especially since it can easily lead to uninitialized instances being used.

Comment: Thanks! I thought about adding a static get method, but the object returned isn't static. Plus I am not the owner of class B, so I'd like to avoid modifying it.

Comment: I just tried with Lookup - my understanding was that the following code should return the ClassB objects, but the collection stays empty:
        Lookup objectsLookup = Lookup.getDefault();
        Template<ClassB>  objectsTemplate = new Template<ClassB>(ClassB.class);
        Result<ClassB> objectsResults = objectsLookup.lookup(objectsTemplate);
        Collection<? extends ClassB> objects = objectsResults.allInstances();

Comment: You should have another class which coordinates the creation of instances of `A` and `B`. Without more details I can't be more specific.

Comment: I have no idea what `Lookup` is. But please edit your question rather than adding details in comments.

Comment: agree with @tgdavies, it is better to use some coordinator. Another solution is to use reflection and probably `ClassLoader` to check is class loaded or not, due to you cannot edit class B